# Socket Exception: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, exception

I have made a multithreaded game emulation server (It uses async sockets).  I have implemented a debugger that allows me to trace thrown exceptions. After some time, the ' An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine' exception pops up - and it happens more and more during time, making the game freeze. According to the debugger the exception is thrown in the catch block of the EndSend method. The program is running on Windows. However, when it ran on linux, another exception was triggered: 'the socket has been shut down'.

What do you think the problem is? I've come up to nothing after days of research on the internet.

Comment: This is nothing unusual.  The client disconnected without saying "bye" nicely.  Of course when you don't have a protocol that lets it say 'bye', to which you can then respond by closing your own socket, then it will happen a lot.

Comment: @HansPassant, and this is why I stay away from sockets. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was the network which couldn't handle too many connections.